# How do I hide a column in Google Sheets from another user with a password?

Tags: google-sheets, privacy

I have a sheet being used by 4 different persons;
one of the columns has private information, related with payments.
I want to be able to see it all the time, but I don't want them to see it, even if we are using the document exactly at the same time.
Is there any way to solve this through a password per example?

Answer (score 0):

A determined user can always discover all of the data in a spreadsheet that they have view or edit access to. The usual recipe to share or publish a subset of data is to create a new viewing spreadsheet and use [importrange()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340) to bring in just the data that you want to show. Note that `importrange()` only works one way, and that the data it shows is view-only.

Use a [middleman](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/25971153?msgid=27808732) spreadsheet to make the viewing spreadsheet bulletproof. The middleman spreadsheet prevents the  use of `importrange()` to "peek around" the source spreadsheet that lets a determined user discover all of the original data. You do not need to grant the viewers any rights to the source spreadsheet or the middleman spreadsheet — they only need to be able to view the viewing spreadsheet.